# c# for each progress loop within the loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-webpages

I have a situation where I am looping through a c# webpages database recordset using for each record in records.

Within that loop I also want to perform another do while loop so that records can be grouped together.

Is it possible to increase the iteration of the for next loop from within the loop..hard to explain but something like this

```
 foreach (var records in records){

 do{
   <p>@records.NAME</p>
   INCREASE THE FOREACH LOOP ITERATION HERE
   currentName = records.NAME //this is now the next name in the recordset
 }while(currentName!=records.NAME)

 }
```

Thanks
Rolf

Comment: Do you mean you want to go to the next iteration of the loop? Then use `continue`.

Comment: what is the `records` type? you could consider using `for` with indexer if `records` is array or `List` for example

Comment: I Think you should have a look at LINQ for these things. Could be as easy as order it and then looping out all results in a normal foreach loop. What you're doing right now seems overly complicated.

Comment: Can't you do it without a do while loop?

Comment: What do you mean by *grouping*? If you need to group something you may want to read about LINQ's `.GroupBy()`

Comment: I'll check out some LINQ stuff..my SQL is decent so hopefully the syntax will be easy to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to do a for loop for this type of method

```
for (int index = 0; index < records.Count - 1; index++){

do{
   <p>@((records)records.Item(index)).NAME</p>
   index++;
   If(index < records.Count) {
      currentName = ((records)records.Item(index)).NAME; //this is now the next name in the recordset
   Else{
      Break;//Breaks out of the while loop because you are done with the for loop }
   }
}while(currentName!=((records)records.Item(index)).NAME)

}
```